# How to smoothly move a UIView with the users finger on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, touch, move

in my app I have a UIImageView representing a chalk. The user can pick that up and drag it over the screen to draw with it.

I implemented that using touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded. In touchesMoved I move the center of my UIImageView to the current touch location and draw a line with core graphics from the last to the current location.

This works well but the image view movement isn't very smooth and it also lags behind the touch. I already tried to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer (didn't recognize the gesture) and a UIScrollView in which I placed the chalk (didn't really figure out how to configure it so that it could be moved far enough in all directions).

Can you give me some hints how to improve the quality of my chalk movement?

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I rewrote how the movement is calculated and it is a little smoother now. Not perfect, but it's enough.

Comment: Hey how did you got solution? Please help me I am facing same problem.

Comment: I reduced the size and performance impact of other parts of the view controller. Helped a little, but as I said not really perfect. Keep in mind that this was a long time ago ... This tutorial shows how to draw smoothly: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164  I think you can adapt some of the mentioned techniques. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following tapGesture method method works smooth for me:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
View* view = (View*)gesture.view;

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    view.dragStartingPoint = CGPointZero;
    return;
}

CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    view.dragStartingPoint = point;
    view.dragStartingFrame = view.frame;

    return;
}

if (CGPointEqualToPoint(view.dragStartingPoint, CGPointZero))
    return;

CGFloat x = view.dragVerticallyOnly? view.frame.origin.x: view.dragStartingFrame.origin.x + point.x - view.dragStartingPoint.x;
CGFloat y = view.dragHorizontallyOnly? view.frame.origin.y: view.dragStartingFrame.origin.y + point.y - view.dragStartingPoint.y;

if (self.dragVerticallyOnly == NO){
    if (x < view.dragMinPoint.x){
        x = view.dragMinPoint.x;
    }
    else if (x  > self.dragMaxPoint.x){
        x = view.dragMaxPoint.x;
    }
}
if (self.dragHorizontallyOnly == NO){
    if (y < view.dragMinPoint.y){
        y = view.dragMinPoint.y;
    }
    else if (y  > self.dragMinPoint.y){
        y = view.dragMinPoint.y;
    }
}

CGFloat deltaX = x - view.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat deltaY = y - view.frame.origin.y;
if ((fabs(deltaX) <= 1.0 && fabs(deltaY) <= 1.0))
    return; // Ignore very small movements

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
}];
```

}

The most important points are:

1. Make the movement with the animated option; (one tenth of a second seems to do the job well done).
2. Avoid making movements when not necessary. Making some calculations will not make it slower, but making unnecessary movements might. However you cannot avoid to many movements otherwise it will not follow the user pan gesture.

Depending on how you want your view to behave, there can be more optimisations that you may want to make.

Remark: My method also takes into account boundaries and movement directions limits that you may define in case you need it. For instance, in my case I added a speed limit. If the user goes beyond a certain pan speed I just ignore further pan gestures and move the view (animated) where the user was pointing to, and at that speed. It may or not make sense in same cases. In mine, it did!

I hope I have been of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the size of the Chalk image u are using....
**Edited:** 
By size i meant the image file size. 
 
It helped me when i faced similar issue.

Comment: I drastically removed the size but it is still lagging behind and the movement isn't really smooth. Also resizing isn't really an option as it is part of the design ...

Answer (score 0):

look at this component : spuserresizableview
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/spuserresizableview

The source code is very simple and can help you to understand the view handling.